# Navigate to a page with parameters not showing in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this line of code to navigate to a page in
my Home controller called Others page. I am passing parameters
and this is all showing in my browser. I think there should be a better 
way of doing this.

Any suggestions please?

```
        window.location.href = "home/Others?deptname=" + departmentName + "?bncode=" + branchCode;


        public ActionResult Others(string deptname, string bncode)
        {       

           return View();
        }
```

Comment: At least part of that code does not look like JavaScript as I know it. Can you provide more details on the languages being used here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a GET request, all the parameters will either need to be shown in the URL or else stored in the user's session.  The latter is considered not a good practice for most things these days.

If you want a cleaner URL, you can configure a route that uses a different pattern, more REST-like, for example: `/departments/{departmentName}`, which might be cleaner. If you need to switch on branch code too that can also be added to the URL path, it really just depends on what your semantics are.